# Rails use picklist in query-ui modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm using query-ui - Dialog - Basic Modal to make a pop-up form for Fullcalender events.  It works great.  But, I would like to add a picklist as one of the input fields in the modal.

The following works as a test:

```
<div id="dialog-form" style="display: none" title="Create new event">
<form>
<fieldset>
  <label for="workorder">Workorder</label>
  <select  name="workorder">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  <label for="hours">Hours (All Day ONLY)</label>
  <input type="floating" name="hours" id="hours" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

The modal displays the select values as options - good so far.

Now I would like to populate the options with data from my workorder table.

How would I do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out =

```
  <%= collection_select(:workorder, :id, Workorder.all, :id, :wonum) %>
```